# progressDialog not dismissing within onReceive

Tags: android, progressdialog, intentservice

I've an app that sends data to the server. My activity implements ResultReceiver.Receiver as it calls an IntentService where i pass the receiver in so that it can send a message back to my activity. I have an onReceive method in my activity that show a progressDialog. It shows correctly but when the service completes and sends back the FINISHED message the progressDialog doesn't dismiss.

Is there a reason why the progress doesn't dismiss?

```
    MyActivity extends Activity implements ResultReceiver.Receiver{

    onCreate(){

    mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
            mReceiver.setReceiver(this);


final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, this, QueryService.class);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
        intent.putExtra("command", "query");

        intent.putExtra("compid", compID);
        intent.putExtra("tagid", tagId);
        intent.putExtra("tagclientid", tagClientId);
        intent.putExtra("carerid", carerID);
        intent.putExtra("formattedtagscantime", formattedTagScanTime);
        intent.putExtra("formattednowtime", formattedNowTime);
        intent.putExtra("statusforwebservice", statusForWbService);
        intent.putExtra("devicename", getDeviceName() + getDeviceName());
        intent.putExtra("taglatitude", tagLatitude);
        intent.putExtra("taglongitude", tagLongitude);

        startService(intent);

    }

        ......
        .....


        @Override
                public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {


                    final int RUNNING = 1;
                    final int FINISHED = 2;
                    final int ERROR = 3;



                    int buildVersionSdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    int buildVersionCodes = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD;

                    Log.e(TAG, "buildVersionSdk = " + buildVersionSdk 
                            + "buildVersionCodes = " + buildVersionCodes);

                    int themeVersion;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

                         themeVersion = 2;

                    }else{

                         themeVersion = 1;
                    }

                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
                    progressDialog.setMessage(" Sending data to server...");
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

                     switch (resultCode) {
                        case RUNNING:
                            //show progress
                            Log.e(TAG, "queryService running");


                            try{
                            progressDialog.show();
                            }catch(Exception e){

                                //ignore
                            }
                            break;
                        case FINISHED:

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            String result = resultData.getString("result");

                            Log.e(TAG, "result in onreceive from posting service = " + result);


                            if( result != null && result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")  ){

                                Log.e(TAG, "about to update DB with servertime");
                                DateTime sentToServerAt = new DateTime();
                                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.updateTransactionWithServerTime(sentToServerAt,null);


                                tagId = null;
                                tagType = null;
                                tagClientId = null;

                                //called to refresh the unsent transactions textview
                                onResume();

                            }else if(result != null && result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Error: TX duplicated")){
                                Log.e(TAG, "response from server is Duplicate Transaction ");


                                //NB. the following time may not correspond exactly with the time on the server
                                //because this TX has already been processed but the 'OK' never reached the phone,
                                //so we are just going to update the phone's DB with the DupTX time so the phone doesn't keep 
                                //sending it.

                                DateTime sentToServerTimeWhenDupTX = new DateTime();
                                nfcscannerapplication.loginValidate.updateTransactionWithServerTime(sentToServerTimeWhenDupTX,null);

                                tagId = null;
                                tagType = null;
                                tagClientId = null;



                            }else{

                                Toast.makeText(NfcscannerActivity.this,
                                        "No phone signal or server problem",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }



                            break;
                        case ERROR:
                            // handle the error;
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            break;
                    }

                }


        }
```

.

```
public class QueryService extends IntentService {

    final int STATUS_RUNNING = 1;
    final int STATUS_FINISHED = 2;
    final int STATUS_ERROR = 3;
    private static final String TAG = QueryService.class.getSimpleName();
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;

    public QueryService() {
        super("QueryService");



    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "inside onHandleIntent in QueryService");

        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication)getApplication();

        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        String command = intent.getStringExtra("command");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if(command.equals("query")) {
            receiver.send(STATUS_RUNNING, Bundle.EMPTY);
            try {
                // get some data or something    




                String compID = intent.getStringExtra("compid");
                String tagID = intent.getStringExtra("tagid");
                String tagClientID = intent.getStringExtra("tagclientid");
                String carerID = intent.getStringExtra("carerid");
                String formattedTagScanTime = intent.getStringExtra("formattedtagscantime");
                String formattedNowTime = intent.getStringExtra("formattednowtime");
                String statusForWebService = intent.getStringExtra("statusforwebservice");
                String deviceName = intent.getStringExtra("devicename");
                String tagLatitude = intent.getStringExtra("taglatitude");
                String tagLongitude = intent.getStringExtra("taglongitude");

                Log.e(TAG, "params in queryservice = " + compID + tagID + tagClientID + carerID + formattedTagScanTime +
                        formattedNowTime + statusForWebService + deviceName + tagLatitude + tagLongitude);


                String result = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.postData(compID, tagID, tagClientID, carerID, formattedTagScanTime,
                        formattedNowTime, statusForWebService, deviceName, tagLatitude, tagLongitude);

                Log.e(TAG, "RESULT FROM POST IN QUERYSERVICE = " + result);

                b.putString("result", result);

               // b.putParcelableArrayList("results", results);
                receiver.send(STATUS_FINISHED, b);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                b.putString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, e.toString());
                receiver.send(STATUS_ERROR, b);
            }    
        }
        this.stopSelf();
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you see in LogCat? Is your `progressDialog` a private variable? If so, try to make it static.

Comment: All the logging looks fine, i get the result back from the server and all the log statements execute ok after the progressDialog.dismiss(). That's why i can't understand why it doesn't dismiss. I've tried making it static but no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant dismiss your progress dialog because you create a new progress dialog every time your app enters onReceive() method.

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion);
```

You see? You create NEW ProgressDialog. And you "loses" link to your previous dialog, so it cant be dismissed. 
Declare your progressDialog as a field of your activity.

For example, if you dont want to change your code at all (but i suggest adding UPLOAD_STARTED case):

```
onCreate() {
    ...
    startReceiving(intent);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog()...
    progressDialog.show()...
}

onReceive(){
    ...
    case ERROR:
        ....
        progressDialog.dismiss();
   case FINISHED:
        ....
        progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean create it in onCreate() and then just show/dismiss it in the onReceive?

Comment: No. First of all, declare it as a field of your activity. Then create it with operator new ONLY in case of upload started. Because you creates it every time you receive a message. Thats no good)

Comment: @turtleboy  I think, you can simply enclose progress dialog creation block with `if (progressDialog == null) { progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare you progressDialog in Class before instantiate it like this:

```
private ProgressDialog progress;
```

then you can do this:

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion);
                progress.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
                progress.setMessage(" Sending data to server...");
                progress.setIndeterminate(true);
```

then somewhere in your code dismiss it like this:

```
pogress.dismiss();
```

Comment: is that not what i do? I have the progressDialog as a member variable of the containing class (My activity), then i instantiate it in the onReceive method with progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(NfcscannerActivity.this, themeVersion);

Comment: You creates it every time you enter onReceive: "progressDialog = new ProgressDialog...". You need to create progressDialog only once.